# mybatis - Passing multiple parameters on @One annotation

Tags: mybatis

I am trying to access a table in my Secondary DB whose name I am obtaining from my Primary DB. My difficulty is to pass the "DB-Name" as a parameter into my secondary query, (BTW I am using MyBatis annotation based Mappers).

This is my Mapper

```
@SelectProvider(type = DealerQueryBuilder.class, method = "retrieveDealerListQuery")
@Results({
    @Result(property="dealerID",                column="frm_dealer_master_id"),
    @Result(property="dealerTypeID",            column="frm_dealer_type_id",        one=@One(select="retrieveDealerTypeDAO")),
    @Result(property="dealerName",              column="frm_dealer_name")
})
public List<Dealer> retrieveDealerListDAO(@Param("firmDBName") String firmDBName);

@Select("SELECT * from ${firmDBName}.frm_dealer_type where frm_dealer_type_id=#{frm_dealer_type_id}")
@Results({
    @Result(property="dealerTypeID",            column="frm_dealer_type_id"),
    @Result(property="dealerType",              column="frm_dealer_type")
})
public DealerType retrieveDealerTypeDAO(@Param("firmDBName") String firmDBName, @Param("frm_dealer_type_id") int frm_dealer_type_id);
```

The firmDBName I have is obtained from my "Primary DB".

- If I omit ${firmDBName} in my second query, the query is trying to access my Primary Database and throws out table "PrimaryDB.frm_dealer_type" not found. So it is basically trying to search for a table named "frm_dealer_type" in my Primary DB.
- If I try to re-write the @Result like

  @Result(property="dealerTypeID", column="firmDBName=firmDBName, frm_dealer_type_id=frm_dealer_type_id", one=@One(select="retrieveDealerTypeDAO")),

It throws an error that Column"firmDBName" does not exist.

- Changing ${firmDBName} to #{firmDBName} also did not help.

I did refer to this blog - [here](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/230)

I want a solution to pass my parameter firmDBName from my primary query into secondary query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation here is that your column must be returned by the first `@SELECT`.
If you look at the test case [here](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/fa62b645d3373ee898e2b4767184de5948739bc7/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/complex_column/PersonMapper.java) you will see that `parent_xxx` values returned by the first Select.
Your DealerQueryBuilder must select `firmDBName` as a return value and your column must map the name of the return column to that.

Your column definition is always wrong, it should be:
`{frm_dealer_type_id=frm_dealer_type_id,firmDBName=firmDBName}` or whatever it was returned as from your first select.

Again you can refer to the test case I have above as well as the documentation here http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Nested_Select_for_Association

Comment: If the column Name that is specified in {parameter_Name=Column_Name} does not exist in the DB Table, how do I pass the value to the parameter_Name in the form of variable, like so
{parameter_Name=_my_variable_}?

Comment: it doesn’t have to be in your dB table, it just has to be returned from the select generated by your sqlprovider. If you are able to provide the java code for that, I can show you how to fix it. If you can’t look at the test case I linked in my answer and you will see how it’s returned by the first select.

Comment: Selected the DB name as the return value and custom column name to map the name of the return column. Got the issue resolved. Thanks